# Очистка Apache

Tags: apache, сервер, ubuntu

Как полностью очистить настройки Apache сервера?

upd.: версия 2.*
Нужно полностью удалить все конфиги.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ну как как... Смотрите местонахождения файла http.conf - это и есть все настройки вашего аппача. Открываете в текстовом редакторе и вперед. Если на дефолт надо скинуть, то можно дефолтный поискать, но все равно пути перепрописывать придется.

Comment: http.conf это далеко не все еого возможные настройки, если вы про 2.х

Comment: да. не все. но в них как раз и прописано и какие модули включать и откуда еще брать настройки. так что в этом файле для аппача именно все настройки. дальше смотреть по инклюдам которые в нем

Comment: Нужно полностью удалить настройки, без восстановления в дефолт.

Comment: удалите этот файл и вообще не будет аппач работать ибо он зависит чисто от него.

Answer (score 0):

За свой опыт в вэб программировании не встречал такого функционала, так что пожалуй только перестановкой дистрибутива.

Comment: Вот этого как раз и не хотелось бы...

Comment: Укажите версию апача. В интернете представленны дефолтные настройки. Можно просто переписать http.conf

Answer (score 0):

в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах это делается командой `purge`, переданной программе `apt`/`apt-get`/`aptitude`.

только надо определить, для какого именно из пакетов следует удалять конфигурационные файлы (`/etc/apache*`).

проще всего их найти, вероятно, так (приведён примерный вывод):

```
$ grep -rl '/etc/apache' /var/lib/dpkg/info/apache*conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apache2.2-common.conffiles
```

в данном случае удалять надо конфигурационные файлы пакета `apache2.2-common`. например, так:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge apache2.2-common
```

по зависимостям будут удалены и все с ним связанные пакеты.

а после завершения операции можно ставить *apache* «с чистого листа» (пакет `apache2.2-common` будет установлен с дефолтными конфигурационными файлами, которые просто вручную приводить к дефолтному виду было бы довольно «муторно»).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get purge apache2`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get install apache2`